# Beautiful Soup find_all with for loop only returning 1st element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I am looking for the total pages with airbnb listings by getting the last page and using that to make a range of pages to loop through.

When using `find_all(loc, {class:id})` and then trying to get all the page numbers in that section, I only return the first row(first page)
The image below shows the rows I want to get the text for, so I can find the max number (10 in this case).
[the rows I want to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkKfd.png)

When I do find all on `div` at that class, it only gives the first page number row, and the `a, aria-label=Next`

I have been playing around with multiple variations of the code below but it always only returns the first row of page numbers(2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

making editable parameters for scraping

```
#checkin and checkout dates
checkin_checkout = ['checkin=2021-05-28&checkout=2021-05-30']
#number of adults for the listing to support
adults = 12
#total beds for the listing
n_beds = adults//2
```

getting the url

```
# url I am using    
nearby = '''https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes?tab_id=
        home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=july&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=june&flexible_trip_lengths
        %5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_picker_type=calendar&
        location_search=NEARBY&
        {}&
        adults={}&
        source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&room_types%5B%5D=
        Entire%20home%2Fapt&place_id=ChIJu-A79dZz44kRGu2B8kV8ylQ&
        min_beds={}'''.format(checkin_checkout, adults, n_beds)
        
res = requests.get(nearby)
print(res.status_code)
```

The part that is not returning what I want

```
#trying to access the html that holds the page numbers range
# shows up like this as buttons on the bottom of the page (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 10)
div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_jro6t0'}) 
for row in div:
    print(row.find_all('a', {'class': '_1y623pm'}))
```

I tried this code and it still only prints the first line of page numbers with the class id is `_1y623pm` and where the text is 2

Comment: Have you tried removing `for row in div:` completely, and then printing the result? (eg: `print(row.find_all('a', {'class': '_1y623pm'})` ) Because you have not provided URLs in your code, I cannot test anything. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be appreciated.

Comment: I updated it to be reproducible, thank you for the link on how to create it! I hope this is correctly formatted. I tried the code suggestion you sent and it is still gives only the first item of that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This would like goes each div boxes
# div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_jro6t0'})
# for row in div:
#     This find only one result of each div-tag but I think it gives only one 
#     of it - like the image.
#     row.find_all('a', {'class': '_1y623pm'})

# First find all div-tags with classname:
div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_jro6t0'}) 
print(div)
# Then find innerhit the found div-tags all a-tags with classname:
a = div.find_all('a', {'class': '_1y623pm'})
for row in a:
    print(row.text)
    print(row.attrs)
```

@BuddyBob: I write comments on the post. More or is it enough?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.